# Diffraction, wave length

Tags: diffraction, wavelength, x-ray-crystallography

I read that when we want to study the structure of a crystal we have to use an electromagnetic wave which has a wave length of approximately the distance between two consecutive atoms in the crystal.

Why is that ? why can't we use a wave length that is 10 time bigger/shorter (or more) ? The calculations still hold , don't they ? (and the diffraction image has still the good dimensions )

Thanks.

Comment: You want to look at Bragg's law. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bragg%27s_law

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page where you have read about crystal structure?

Comment: @Godparticle: I've read it in a french book and I can't find anything online to relate to it

Comment: @eqb: does Bragg's law says that lambda must be close to  the distance between two neighboring atoms ? I can't find anything that contradicts what I've said .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Bragg's law:

$$ \sin\theta = \frac{n\lambda}{d} $$

In a typical X-ray diffractometer it's experimentally convenient to have $\theta$ around $\pi/2$ (we actually measure $2\theta$ in the diffractometer so $\theta = \pi/2$ means the line appears at 90° to the incoming beam). If $\theta$ is much bigger the diffraction line disappears off the end of our film, and if $\theta$ is too small all the lines are clustered together at small angle and we can't see the small detail.

Suppose we choose $\lambda = 10d$, then we get:

$$ \sin\theta = \frac{10nd}{d} = 10n \ge 10$$

because $n \ge 1$, and there is no solution i.e. we get no line. OK, lets suppose we choose $\lambda = d/10$, then we get:

$$ \sin\theta = \frac{nd}{10d} = \frac{n}{10} $$

In this case we can get values for $\sin\theta$ in a useful range by choosing lines with large values of $n$. The trouble is that the line intensity drops rapidly with increasing $n$ and by the time we get to $n = 5 - 10$ the intensity has dropped so much we need long exposure times.

So wavelengths of around $\lambda = d$ are the only ones that are experimentally useful.

**Footnote:**

$d$ isn't (necessarily) the distance between atoms. It's the distance between planes in the lattice and will typically between 1 and 0.1 times the unit cell dimensions. The distance between atoms can't be bigger than the unit cell but it can be a lot smaller if the structure is complex.